# Make Mail remember that I’ve loaded remote content

Tags: mail.app

I have *Load remote content* turned off in my Mail settings, so I have to click to load remote content on each individual e-mail. This is fine and works as expected (a bit annoying that you can’t whitelist senders or domains, but I can live with that).

It’s annoying, however, that as soon as I click away from an e-mail – say, to read a different e-mail – the remote content that Mail has loaded **disappears**, and I have to click *Load remote content* **again** on the same e-mail.

Presumably loading remote content involves downloading that content and saving it into one of Mail’s myriad temp folders, so I can see no logical reason why it should be wiped again as soon as I click away from the e-mail.

Is there a way to force Mail to remember that it’s already loaded the content in a given e-mail and just reload it from the temp folder the next time I open that e-mail?

---

Not sure if it makes a difference, but I’m currently running macOS 10.15.5 on a Mac mini (2018), running Mail 13.4 (3608.80.23.2.2).

Comment: I highly suspect you mean macOS 10.15.5, since 10.5 was Leopard back in 2007?

Comment: @X_841 Oops, yes, 10.15.5. Fixed.

Comment: I have the same problem. I cannot understand why Apple doesn't remember this or provide a whitelist. And all the apple fans seem to not bother ... that is so annoying!